# Insert an element before and after substring

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you insert substrings between  elements using regular expressions or an alternative form in javascript/jQuery?

For example I have the following string:

> `This is a string 015 with numbers 1486453 randomly 10 inserted
>   between words 0954`

If my regex is to find all numbers, the result would be the following:

> `This is a string <span>015</span> with numbers <span>1486453</span>
>   randomly <span>10</span> inserted between words <span>0954</span>`

Comment: You can do with Simple Javascript *replace* function. No need to use the jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var testStr = 'This is a string 015 with numbers 1486453 randomly 10 inserted between words 0954';    
var result = testStr.replace(/(\d+)/gi, '<span>$1</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = $el.text();
$el.html(str.replace(/\d+/g, "<span>$&</span>"));
```

If your element already contains html nodes, it gets more complicated. You'd need to build a DOM iterator - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10416898/1048572).