# Regular Expression that doesn't match html tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, highlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [highlight words in html using regex & javascript - almost there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416643/highlight-words-in-html-using-regex-javascript-almost-there)

UPDATE --> The final script, once resolved, is, that one:

```
var regex;
var filterSize;

function normalizar(str) {
    var fin=str.toLowerCase().replace('á','a').replace('é','e').replace('í','i').replace('ó','o').replace('ú','u');

    return fin;
}

function highlight(fin) {
    htmlFin="";
    while ((match = regex.exec(normalizar(fin))) != null) {
        posIni=match.index;
        posEnd = posIni+filterSize;
        var ini="";
        if (posIni != 0) ini=fin.substring(0, posIni);
        var sub=fin.substring(posIni, posEnd);
        fin=fin.substring(posEnd, fin.length);

        htmlFin += ini+"<span class='highlight'>"+sub+"</span>";
    }
    htmlFin += fin;

    return htmlFin;
}

function procesar(elemento) {
    elemento.children().each(function() {
        var mas=$(this).children().size();
        if (mas == 0) {
            $(this).html(highlight($(this).text()));
        } else {
            procesar($(this));
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".filter").keyup(function(){

        // Cogemos el texto de búsqueda
        var filter = $(this).val();
        //Ponemos el contador a 0
        var count = 0;
        $('span.highlight').each(function() {
            $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
        });

        //Por cada elemento de la lista...
        $(".list tr:not(:first-child)").each(function(){
            var html=$(this).html();
            var posIni = -1;
            var posEnd = -1;

            filterNorm=normalizar(filter);
            filterSize=filter.length;
            regex=new RegExp(filterNorm, 'gi');
            var buscar=normalizar($(this).text()).search(regex);
            var htmlFin="";
            if (buscar > -1) {
                if (filter) procesar($(this));
                $(this).show();
                count++;

            } else $(this).fadeOut();
        });

        // Actualizamos la cuenta
        if (filter) {
            var numberItems = count;
            //Si no hay coincidencias lo mostramos en rojo.
            if (count==0) $(".cuenta").html("<span class='error'>Coincidencias = "+count+"</span>");
            else $(".cuenta").text("Coincidencias: "+count);
            //Si no hay filtro, limpiamos el html de cuentas.
        } else $(".cuenta").text("");
    });
});
```

The goal to make a search script with jquery/javascript that highlight the matches within a  from an input. It must ignore case and diacritics (accents) signs and html tags

I'm so close to do it, but It fails cause it doesn't ignore html tags, I mean, the script highlight html tags matches as well...

For example:

UPDATE: You can try the script here  [jsfiddle.net/josecash/nD6dg/2](http://jsfiddle.net/josecash/nD6dg/2), just type td or < or > to see the error.

Lets say I have a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Kind</th><th>Type</th></tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Fedora</strong></td>
<td>Linux</td>
<td>Operative System</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If I type the letter o in the input, my script will highlight the o in Fed**o**ra, and in **O**perating System, but also the o in the tag str**o**ng.

I suppose I can do that with a regular expression in the regex var, but I can't figure it out...

Any help would be really appreciate

The script looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".filter").keyup(function(){

        // Input text
        var filter = $(this).val();
        //Ponemos el contador a 0
        var count = 0;
        $('span.highlight').each(function() {
            $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
        });

        //Foreach tr in the table
        $(".list tr:not(:first-child)").each(function(){
            var html=$(this).html();
            var posIni = -1;
            var posEnd = -1;

                    // normalizar just replace accents
            filterNorm=normalizar(filter);
            var filterSize=filter.length;
            var regex=new RegExp(filterNorm, 'gi');
            var buscar=normalizar($(this).text()).search(regex);
            var htmlFin="";

            if (buscar > -1) {
                if (filter) {
                    var end=html;
                    while ((match = regex.exec(normalizar(end))) != null) {
                        posIni=match.index;
                        posEnd = posIni+filterSize;
                        var ini="";
                        if (posIni != 0) ini=end.substring(0, posIni);

                        var sub=end.substring(posIni, posEnd);
                        end=end.substring(posEnd, end.length);

                        htmlFin += ini+"<span class='highlight'>"+sub+"</span>";
                    }
                    htmlFin += end;
                }
                if (filter) $(this).show().html(htmlFin);
                else $(this).show();
                count++;
            } else $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You're calling `.split()` but you never use the result (the variable "sp"). Why?

Comment: Sorry, I've cleaned the code, that was just for trying

Comment: If you have full control over the contents of the table, then you *may* be able to avoid HTML markup within cells, eg. `<td class="strong">Fedora</td>`, where your stylesheet provides the styling with the directive `.strong { font-weight:bold; }`.

Comment: I don't have the full control of the table, It can contain all kind of tags, anyway, in your example if I type td the script will highlight the <td> tag...

Comment: In that case, the code is fundamentally flawed. Within each tr, you need to loop through each td and address its text.

Comment: @josecash - to mark a question as 'solved', just tick the answer below that you prefer (or leave it where you don't find any answer helpful). Ticking an answer rewards people who have helped you.

Comment: Also, post-solution answers of your own are best entered into SO as answers, rather than question edits. Questions should be kept useful for future readers, and it's a bit confusing to have the answer as the first thing in a question `;)`. Edit: it's not possible if the question has been closed, however - maybe a Pastie link added as a comment instead?

Comment: Yes, question should be reverted to the original and an answer added (and accepted) to reflect the eventual answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Josecash,

A good way to avoid handling the HTML markup itself is to :

- discover child nodes with plain javascript rather than jQuery
- treat text nodes as they are encountered
- penetrate further into element nodes (recursively) as they are encountered.

The overall code will be something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Highlighter function
    function highlight(text) {
        //Your highlight code here
        //...
        //return text with added HTML markup
    }

    //Recursive scanner function to penetrate the DOM tree.
    function scanNode(index, node) {
        //node is a plain javascript reference to a DOM node, not jQuery-wrapped.
        if(node.nodeType == 3) {//hurray, it's a TEXT_NODE
            $(node).replaceWith(highlight(node.nodeValue));
        }
        else if(node.nodeType == 1){//it's an ELEMENT_NODE
            //Here, for convenience, we use jQuery's utility `.each() method
            //but we are still essentially working in plain javascript.
            $.each(node.childNodes, scanNode);
        }
    }

    var $list = $(".list");
    //master routine
    $(".filter").keyup(function() {
        $list.find('span.highlight').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.replaceWith($this.text());
        }).find("tr:gt(1)").each(scanNode);
    });
});
```

*With thanks to @Bergi for his input below*

You will have to write the `highlight()` function, which will be a fairly light modification of the code you posed above. Make sure the function returns the marked up text string.

The critical line `$(node).replaceWith(highlight(node.nodeValue));` has been tested (in Opera 12.12 and IE9); [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YphgN/)

Everything else is untested so may need debugging.

Comment: +1. You might make `scanNode` accept an index parameter or work on the `thisArg`, so that you can directly use it in `.each()`. Also, as your function is recursive anayway, I see no reason not to start with the `<tr>` elements :-)

Comment: @Bergi, I'm amazed, you have actually gone through and checked my code. Thank you. I can't quite see what you mean by passing an index parameter ... - I'm sure it's just me being thick. Starting with the `<tr>` elements (thence their `<td>`s) was just a way of implementing the OP's jQuery "not(:...)" exclusion prior to starting the recursion, thus allowing `scanNode()` to work with nodes and not need to handle a jQuery collection internally. I toyed with other approaches and ended up with something that should work - I'm sure there must be many other ways to skin this particular cat.

Comment: If the function's signature was `function scanNode(index, node)`, you could just use `$list.find("tr:gt(1)").each(scanNode)` and `$.each(node.childNodes, scanNode)`.

Comment: Yes, of course, silly me. I will edit the answer.

Comment: It's done, thanks all, and specially the one who give me the clue Beetroot-Beetroot and the one who show me jsFiddle (I don't know how I've been living without it...) Bergi, thanks for your time. Finally, as Beetroot-Beetroot suggested, I did it with recursion in nodes, but I've used jquery instead of plain jquery, sorry, simplifies my life so much...I have updated my first post with the final code.

Comment: My code works with plain javascript `node.childNodes` for a very good reason; because jQuery's `.children()` (like other selectors and selection methods) filters out text nodes. So if a node contains a mixture of text nodes and element nodes, then by your `.children()` approach, the text nodes will not be processed.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use 'html' as your regex testing string, use the resulting text instead.
Test following code:

```
if (filter) {
      //replace this line:: var end=html;  by
      var end= $(this).text();
    ....
}
```

Comment: If I do that, the positions given inside the while loop (posIni and posEnd) won't be correct.

Comment: Could you explain problem using this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pyFry/     ??? {have remove normalizar function}

Comment: To be honest I don't know how to use it...But I'll try...

Comment: I've made this http://jsfiddle.net/josecash/nD6dg/2/ if you type, for example, the letter t, the error comes up...