# detecting numbers or letters with css/js

Tags: javascript

I want to detect and style a special letter .
for example something like this
:

> body["p"] /
>   body["2"]

how can I do this?
thanks

Comment: You cannot with pure CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this on a node-by-node basis with a fairly simple replace, but it wouldn't scale very well.

Given the markup:

```
<p>Peter Rabbit ate all of Potter's pickling cukes.</p>
```

If you wanted to add a style to all of the letters **p** in this text, you could select the paragraph node and add spans around any **p** (assuming a single paragraph):

```
var graf = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
graf.innerHTML = graf.innerText.replace(/(p)/gi,'<span class="fancy">$1</span>');
```

That said, this would only work on plain text nodes; if you had, for example, a `span` tag already in the `p` tag, it'd get mucked up by the replace.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot with CSS. The only non-element (css-created) [pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements) are `::first-line` and `::first-letter`.

However, you could search with JS through the DOM and create tags around the letters to be highlighted. Check [highlight words in html using regex & javascript - almost there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10416643/1048572) for how to do that.

Comment: thanks, what is the problem with this tiny code? '    var a=getElementById("b")
    if a!=NaN {style.color="blue"}'

Comment: @user1599537 the problem with that code is that it 1) doesn't work and 2) is riddled with errors.

Comment: @user1599537: What is it supposed to do? Your current snippet looks up an element with the id "b", compares it against `NaN` (which it oviously is not equal to) and then sets a property on a variable named `style`.