# Avoid unhooking Eventhandlers when using .replace() function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to replace all Instances of "®" with "< sup >®< sup >" in the body of a website. But if I use the replace function, all the Eventhandlers that are attached get unhooked. How can I avoid that?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sw81rv4g/1/)

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\u00AE/, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
```

Comment: Can you give an example? Display some source code in a snippet for us to view or jsfiddle? We debug you code, give us something to work with. Thank you.

Comment: Use the DOM, instead of fiddling with HTML strings  (have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10416898/1048572)). Also, try to do it serverside, and you won't have any problems.

Comment: You have to iterate through the text nodes and replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you replace your whole document innerHTML to change every instance of ®. This will result in the destruction of all HTML elements contained in your document and the creation of a set of totally new ones. That is the reason your event handlers get *unhooked*.

To do this without loosing your event handlers you would have to iterate over every element (or at least every element which could contain a ®) and only replace it's innerHTML if it contains an ®. But even this could kill some of your event handlers if the constellation is unfortunate.

Another solution could be to use another font for the ®. With webfonts it is possible to load fonts that only contain certain characters. That way you could replace the font used for the ® with a font that already displays it superscripted.