# Inject HTML behind found string and preserve original HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, string

I need to inject some html into a text while preserving the original html. It doesn't matter if it's in javascript or php.

As an example.
Base Test:

```
Die geis­tes– und sozi­al­wis­sen­schaft­li­che
Aus­ein­an­der­set­zung mit <em>Human Enhan­ce­ment</em> hat erneut zu
Debat­ten über den Sta­tus des Men­schen als Cyborg geführt.
```

Then I got the same thing as html-stripped string.
Search String:

```
Die geis­tes– und sozi­al­wis­sen­schaft­li­che
Aus­ein­an­der­set­zung mit Human Enhan­ce­ment hat erneut zu
Debat­ten über den Sta­tus des Men­schen als Cyborg geführt.
```

I can search by the second string, but need to inject some html behind the first one.
Result:

```
Die geis­tes– und sozi­al­wis­sen­schaft­li­che
Aus­ein­an­der­set­zung mit <em>Human Enhan­ce­ment</em> hat erneut zu
Debat­ten über den Sta­tus des Men­schen als Cyborg geführt.<span>1</span>
```

It's not that easy ... :) I can find and replace the string via Regex and jQuery's .text() function. But that doesn't preserve the original html.

Comment: Why not use `jQElem.append()` if you're using jquery or `document.querySelector(<your selector>).innerHTML += <span>text</span>` if you're not using jQuery ?

Comment: Because the found text can be inside a <p> in example. I need the <span> to be exactly behind the found text, not the html element.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275446/how-to-wrap-part-of-a-text-in-a-node-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by modifiny the search sentence with regex. Replaced all spaces with

```
\s*?(?:<\/?[^>]*?>)?\s*?
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/nI0vY7/1

Answer (score 0):

php:
  strpos + length of your needle to get the end position of it in a string as $index, then  substr_replace($string, $insertion, $index, 0);

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = "I want to add before this element";
function Add($add, $before, $in_content)
    {
        $p = strpos($in_content, $before, 0);
        if ($p !== false)
           return substr_replace( $in_content , $add , $p, 0 );
        else
           return false;
    }

    $result = Add("paragraph ","this",$string);
    if($result !== false)
        echo $result;
?>
```

Do you need to get the text from html dom or from database or file?

Javascript:

```
<div id="content">I want to add before this element</div>
<script>

var text_content = document.getElementById("content").innerText;
function Add(add, before, in_content)
    {
        var p = in_content.indexOf(before);
        if (p !== -1)
            return [in_content.slice(0, p), add, in_content.slice(p-1)].join('');
        else
            return false;

    }

    var result = Add("paragraph","this",text_content);
    if(result !== false)
        document.getElementById("content").innerText = result;
</script>
```

Comment: If you need to get it from the dom parse and put back i can create this function in javascript + jquery!

Comment: There is Javascript, hope it helped! If you need to add the string after some text, tell me and i will change, cause i didn't understand, before or after!