# Whitespace when hiding text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hide

In the sample code below , on large blocks of text I am getting copious amounts of white space (blank lines) after filtering the text.

The issue predominantly manifests with the `<span>`-tags, but in my actual code (JQuery targeting an iframe) I am getting the same issue with `<p>` or `li` elements tagged with the `.vis` class.

In the example below,

- the first few items display correctly (just the matched lines displayed; no extra white space);
- later items filtered / selected (exemplified by the `<span>`-tagged text) are pushed down, below white space.

For example, type `lemon` or `mango` ("ok"), and compare to `soup` or `tea` (extra white space).

---

- JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vstuart/fqw0p4dg/1/

---

```js
$('#snippets_search_box').keyup(function() {

  const valThis = this.value;
  const length = this.value.length;
  $('.vis').each(function() {
    const text = $(this).text().replace(/<span class=\"vis\">/gi, "").replace(/<\/span>/gi, "");

    const position = text.indexOf(valThis.toLowerCase());

    if (position !== -1) {
      const matches = text.substring(position, (valThis.length + position));
      const regex = new RegExp(matches, 'ig');
      const highlighted = text.replace(regex, `<mark>${matches}</mark>`);
      $(this).html(highlighted).show();
    } else {
      $(this).text();
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
input {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

div {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  //margin: 10px 10px;
}

p.vis {
  clear: left;
  margin: 0.0rem 0.0rem 0.0rem 0.0rem;
}

span.vis {
  clear: left;
  color: brown;
  margin: 0.0rem 0.0rem 1.0rem 0.0rem;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

table td {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--
BASED ON:

* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59178447/search-and-highlight-text-on-page-while-keeping-html-structure
  
* https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/6x3ak5d0/7/
-->

<head>
  <input placeholder="Filter these results" id="snippets_search_box" type="text" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p class="vis">apples</p>
    <p class="vis">bananas</p>
    <p class="vis">cakes</p>
    <p class="vis">donuts</p>
    <li class="vis">eggs</li>
    <li class="vis">fish</li>
    <li class="vis">grapes</li>

    <li class="vis">ham</li>
    <li class="vis">ice cream</li>
    <li class="vis">jello</li>
    <li class="vis">kefir</li>
    <li class="vis">lemon</li>

    <span class="vis">mango</span><br />
    <span class="vis">nachos</span><br />
    <span class="vis">oranges</span><br />
    <span class="vis">peaches</span><br />
    <span class="vis">quiche</span><br />
    <span class="vis">radishes</span><br />
    <span class="vis">soup</span><br />
    <span class="vis">tea</span><br />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: because you do not hide the `<br>` after the element

Comment: @epascarello : thank you, that was precisely my issue. In my code I was programmatically constructing filtered results (text "snippets"), and was adding the `<br>` element. Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/59368164/1904943 I replaced it with <wbr>, which seems to resolve the issue. Question for you (noting your vastly superior StackOverflow experience): should I delete this question, or in your opinion: do you think contributes any value?  (If the latter, please post your comment and I'll accept the answer.)

Comment: you can use add/remove css class instead using show/hide to have better control